# Why html5 canvas tag uses PI value to draw circle?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cir = c.getContext("2d");
cir.beginPath();
cir.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2* Math.PI );
cir.stroke();
```

or

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cir = c.getContext("2d");
cir.beginPath();
cir.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 6.14);
cir.stroke();
```

This two code can draw a full circle so in this why we are using pi value in this ?

Comment: that is weird question... ever heard about geometry?

Comment: By using a value more than `2*Math.PI` you just overdraw the circle. However by using values less that `2*Math.PI` you can create uncomplete circle (exactly what is says - arc). This is how it works: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_arc.gif

Comment: create a circle with bigger radius and you'll able to notice that `6.14` does not create full circle. The difference is so small now , that you are not seeing it with naked eyes. Zoom in the page, it may help.

Answer (score 8):

Angles can be measured with a variety of different measures. The most common are:

- [Degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29), where `360` degrees equals one full circle
- [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), where the mathematical constant `π` (Greek letter Pi) — which is roughly 3.14159265 — is one half circle, and a full circle is `2π`.

The [`arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#arc%28%29) function takes angles in radians, so passing the values `startAngle=0` and `endAngle=2*Math.PI` will draw a complete circle with radius `radius` from point `(x,y)`.

Edit:
The line of code that you posted:

```
cir.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 6.14);
```

Will draw *most* of a circle, as `6.14 < 2π`. 2π is approximately 6.283185, so the arc will be about 98% of a full circle.

Answer (score 1):

Its using [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as the unit of measure to describe the angle of the arc.  This is very common in programming languages, especially in graphics programming.  A full circle, 360 degrees, is equal to 2 * PI Radians.

Comment: It's very common in programming languages because it's common in math and engineering. Only when you get down to drawing blueprints and plans do you convert to degrees for your machinists and technicians.

Answer (score 1):

Value of `Math.PI: 3.141592653589793` is more accurate. And `cir.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 6.14);` does not make full circle.

Answer (score 1):

The second code does not draw a full circle: there is a gap on the right. The reason is that 6.14 is less than a full circle (in radians), which is 2π, about 6.28. It is common to use the property `Math.PI` for π in JavaScript, since it gives a very accurate approximation (the most accurate approximation achievable using a double precision floating point number in the system).

P.S. This is not about the `canvas` tag but about JavaScript code that draws on a canvas specified by a `canvas` element.

Comment: That's because the other answer did not answer the question. At best it was a comment. The question is why 2pi? At the very least this answer mentions that 2pi radians defines a full circle.

Comment: @slebetman, Do you think anyone of these 4 answers is an answer to the question?

Comment: Yes. The answer is that it's simply using radians instead of degrees. So far Der Flatulator's answer is most complete while GrandmasterB's answer was the first direct answer to the question.

Comment: Radians vs. degrees was not the issue. The question was why `2* Math.PI` is used instead of `6.14`.